# Proteus Circuit LED does not work

Tags: led, proteus, diagram

[image]

I am trying to build a double dice circuit. I tried one example I found from the  web. But, I have problems with leds, and I am not very familiar with proteus. Could you please tell me why my LEDs are not working?

[Original source:](http://www.teknoprojeler.com/elektronik-tavla-zari-yapimi/)

RM: Found elsewhere - similar and may be meant to be identical - may be clearer. 
[From](http://store.donanimhaber.com/78/57/69/78576905D036E2804BBA66BB43833AAB.jpg)

[image]

Comment: D4 is reversed as shown. Current must flow from +ve to gnd in direction of LED arrows.

Comment: At first glance the it doesn't appear to be a good design. Next what do are your trying to achieve? Do want to learn Proteus? If so check this link [Electronic circuit simulation using Proteus -Tutorial 1-LEDs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKVf_Hj00vs) Also you need to add power to the 4018 and 4011 circuit which I don't see in your simulation circuit

Comment: Is this an assignment? Somebody posted the exact same circuit yesterday. Do you have to use this circuit? They are being very "clever" with all sorts of tricks to make the circuit work - it relies on the 4011's being able to both drive the LEDs and also other gates as well. There are much "cleaner" ways of doing this if you do not have to use this circuit.

Comment: LEDS: Place an LED plus a 1K in series across 5 volts - it should light. If not, reverse polarity (swap leads) of LED and try again. If it lights neither way LED is probably dead. Some LEDs will die with 5V reverse polarity but not usually. | What colour are LEDs? What is your supply voltage? This WILL NOT WORK with white LEDs on 5V as eg D6 & D4 are in series and driven by 4011 . THey are using 9 volts [**Here**](http://u.jimdo.com/www400/o/s625152f12579bb4f/img/i285d618cf4a20194/1279214141/std/zar.jpg) - what are you using?

Comment: A 4011 IC typically has quite low current drive eg [ONSEMI MC14001B](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC14001B-D.PDF) 2.25 mA typical at Vdd = 10V (with 0.5V change in level when loaded). At Vdd = 9V, Vhi will be about 8.5V at 2 mA. Two red LEDs + 1K as shown should give slightly more than 2 mA. Red LEDs will operate but not very bright.

Answer (score 1):

**ORIGINAL - NOT recommended.**

The original circuit is a lashup design with a number of shortcomings which make it hard to guarantee operation. The suggested alternative below is intentionally 'designed' at the same sort of level but has fewer compromises. (Diode OR gates, "interesting" reset cct).

The original is designed to be  operated on about 9 Volts. It will not work on 5V (or less).

D4 is reversed as shown. Current must flow from +ve to gnd in direction of LED arrows. –

Ensure there is power on the 4018 and 4011 circuits.

A 4011 IC typically has quite low current drive eg ONSEMI MC14001B 2.25 mA typical at Vdd = 10V (with 0.5V change in level when loaded). At Vdd = 9V, Vhi will be about 8.5V at 2 mA. Two red LEDs + 1K as shown should give slightly more than 2 mA. Red LEDs will operate but not very bright.

---

**ALTERNATIVE**

The circuit below is 'out of my head' and untested but should work OK.

Even if you do not build this circuit, just understanding it should teach you a lot - and the basic ideas can be used elsewhere.

This is about as low level as the other circuit but uses (almost) no "tricks" and can drive LEDs to whatever brightness is required. It will run on 5V if desired.
This is offered mainly as an "idea starter"  but could be tidied up and refined slightly if thought to be useful. It should work as is.

IC1 is a CD4017 10 output decoded counter. [**Datasheet**](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/CD4017BC,%20CD4022BC.pdf)
It is clocked by an external clock as per the original or some other clock source.
When it reaches output 7 it resets to the start.
**NB Outputs are shown as  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... but on IC are 0 1 2 3 4 5 6**
Enable lines on CD4017 that are not driven need to be connected high or low as appropriate.

IC2 is any driver IC that accepts high signals to enable an LED on the driven channel(s).
This could be 4 transistors or a ULN280x or similar.
[ULN2803 data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2803a.pdf)
As the ULN280x drivers have 8 drivers a single IC can be used for 2 dice (4 drivers each). 
7 LEDs are driven in a die / dice shape.
LEDs are numbered 1...7 and arranged as shown at bottom right.
The array at top right has the LEDs in the array arranged in order 4 1 7 3 5 2 6 as shown.
There are only 4 groups of LEDs.
A is centre spot, used for numbers 1, 3, 5
B is left top, bottom right used for numbers 2, 3, 5, 6
C is the other diagonal
D is the 2 centre horizontal LEDs.

The only trick is the use of 13 diodes as OR gates.
Fewer diodes could have been used by using LEDs in series but littl would be gained and it's harder to follow.

CD4017 output 1 drives channel A = centre spot = dice-1

CD4017 output 2 drives channel B = which drives LEDs 1 & 7 = top left and bottom right = dice 2.

Here is where the fun begins :-)

CD4017 output 3 drives channels A AND B via two diodes so LED 2 is lit by channel A and LEDs 1&7 are lit by channel B so in total 1 2 7 are lit = dice-3

And so on.

CD4017 output 7 going high places a high on the Cd4017 reset pin via reset diode and output 1 is selected. The reset time is arranged to be short compared to clock rate.
A 0.01 uF cap and 10k pull down are shown but adjust to suit clock speed. The cap is used as without it the IC may start to reset and then remove its drive and so achieve a partial reset. While there is no formal hysteresis here it does in fact work very reliably in practice.

The CD4017 could be one with a Schmitt triggered clock but this is probably not needed in practice in this application.

This circuit does not have the LED drive limitations of the original.

Total parts for 2 dice is
1 x ULN2803 driver, 2 x CD4017, 14 LEDs, 14 x iN4148 diodes, 8 x R, 1 x c, clock source.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First this schematic is not very readable and it's a mess. Try to reorder everything so that is clear and nice, that there are as less line crosses as possible. Second it's not clear what is your supply voltage, a led in simulation won't work in one case - the current is too low. If you have a led with a voltage drop 2V is requiring minimum say 5mA and you are supplying 3.3V then in case you put an resistor 10K your current will be (3.3-2)/10K=0.13mA. So in this case you will need at least something like 15V supply voltage to see leds on.

So shortly remake the schematic nice and clear, state your supply voltage, calculate the resistances and should work out. If not we'll check the counters...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 5V for VDD the leds will not lit in Proteus, with the configuration you have.
Just for the simulation, avoid using 1K resistors for leds. use 100 ohm resistors.